# what is the difference between symbol and weakmap in javascript private methods?

Tags: javascript, private-members

I see using symbol and weak map  to create private members inside an object. are they similar? they both assigned to the a property outside the object and then get called inside the object.

```
   const _length=Symbol() or const _length=new Weakmap()
```

I understand symbol() easily however I do not get weakmap. In which case I should use weakmap or Can I use symbol all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a full example for each of these techniques:

```js
const Foo = (() => {
  const _length = Symbol('_length');

  return class Foo {
    [_length] = 0;

    get length () { return this[_length]; }
    set length (value) { this[_length] = value; }
  }
})();

const bar = new Foo();

console.log(bar.length);
```

```js
const Foo = (() => {
  const _length = new WeakMap();

  return class Foo {
    constructor () { _length.set(this, 0); }

    get length () { return _length.get(this); }
    set length (value) { _length.set(this, value); }
  }
})();

const bar = new Foo();

console.log(bar.length);
```

However, the [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol) approach is not truly private, as demonstrated here:

```js
const Foo = (() => {
  const _length = Symbol('_length');

  return class Foo {
    [_length] = 0;

    get length () { return this[_length]; }
    set length (value) { this[_length] = value; }
  }
})();

const bar = new Foo();
const _length = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bar)[0]; // private key exposed

console.log(bar[_length]); // private property exposed
```

The reason that [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) is recommended for the second approach is because it allows instances of the `class Foo` to be garbage collected when they are no longer referenced anywhere else in the program.

In contrast, a normal [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will hold a strong reference to each instance and prevent it from being garbage collected, which leads to memory leaks in the program.

There's also now a third approach that should eventually make its way into the ECMAScript specification: [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields) which are part of the TC39 class fields proposal currently in Stage 3.

```js
class Foo {
  #length = 0;

  get length () { return this.#length; }
  set length (value) { this.#length = value; }
}

const bar = new Foo();

console.log(bar.length);
```

In contrast to the `Symbol` approach, these are truly private properties. In addition, they're much easier to write than when using the approach with `WeakMap`.

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages for using one of these methods? When would one method be preferred over another method?

Comment: @Sukima Ideally I'd suggest using the private fields syntax and [babel](https://babeljs.io/) with [`@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object), which by default transforms your code into the ES6 `WeakMap` approach I've shown above.